# ¿Como puedo utilizar el metodo findindex en una función?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Hola lo que quiero hacer es una función del método findindex, no logro implementarla ya que el elemento actual que está siendo procesado en el array, no lo puedo pasar como parámetro ¿Alguna idea?.
¿Como debo pasaar los parametros?

```
function indice(array,objectId, payloadId) {
    
    const index = array.findIndex( () => objectId === payloadId)

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el para el metodo findIndex, debes declarar que quieres que busque, ejemplo:

```
let arr = ["madrid", "barcelona", "cadiz", "sevilla"];
let index = arr.findIndex(n => n === "madrid");
return index;
```

**Resultado "0**

Por tanto en tu código yo haría algo asi:

```
// Incluyo objectId por si viene de algun sitio, pero en caso de que no, se puede eliminar.
function indice (array, objectId, payloadId) {
let a = objectId;
const index = array.findIndex(a => a === payloadId);

return index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:
-Tu lo que quieres es conseguir el index de un elemento del array, entonces...
Ejemplo:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

function indice(array, payloadId) {
    
    const index = array.findIndex(a => a === payloadId)

    return index;

}

let foundIndex = indice(arr, 3);
```

Lo que obtendras será el índice del número que mandes como parámetro. El método findIndex ejecuta una función en cada uno de los elementos del array hasta que devuelve true al coincidir con la condición. Si no, devuelve un -1, lo cuál quiere decir que ese número no existe en el array.

Answer (score 0):

El "*elemento actual que está siendo procesado en el array*" en las funciones de Javascript que tienen "callback" se pasa "automáticamente"

```js
const un_array = [10,9,8,7];

function un_callback(elemento_actual_que_está_siendo_procesado) {
  console.log("hacemos algo con ", elemento_actual_que_está_siendo_procesado);
}

un_array.findIndex(un_callback); // <-- El elemento que está siendo procesado se pasa automaticamente
```